# What is a good practice when using constants versus literals?

Tags: c#, coding-style, constants

I'm writing an application, and I want to make sure I have a good coding standard when it comes to constants and literals. The thing is, I'm not completely sure where I should use constants, and where using constants is just going overboard! For example...

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    public const string WindowTitle = "This seems like overkill!";

    public MyWindow() : base()
    {
        this.Title = WindowTitle;
    }
}
```

So my question is, what are the most widely-accepted criteria for deciding on what should be declared as a constant, and what shouldn't? I'm guessing that anything that's used in one place only should be a literal (such as a title of a window), and anything used several times should be a constant?

Comment: I don't think there is a good answer for this, at least within rules of SO. There is no way to measure "most widely-accepted" and so the answer would be subjective. Personally I think your idea (one use vs many uses) makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Is `WindowTitle` ever going to change? If not, `const` is acceptable.

Comment: In your example, I would probably say that a `const` _is_ overkill, but to know for sure would require knowing the rest of the hypothetical code. I would probably mark `WindowTitle` as `private` if keeping the `const` though.

Comment: Thankyou @AndreyShchekin. I realise that there may be no right or wrong answer, but I wondered if there's some general rule-of-thumb that could guide me.  Even though the idea I'm thinking of does make some sense, it seems to break the whole "magic number" thing. For example, my main window has a 'LinearGradientBrush' composed using 2 colours that it uses as its background, and I can't decide whether I should be declaring these as constants (using 'public static readonly'), or whether I should avoid this in order to make my code less bloated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constants are meant to denote constant variables and help the compiler to make optimizations and help the programmer to not change stuff that isn't meant to be changed.

Since there are no widely used specifications on this topic it's up to you how perfect you want to write your code and the size of your project. I'd say that the best practice would be to use `const` whereever possible. It normally doesn't happen that often anyway to really become a problem and programming-style-wise it's good practice for nice and good coding.

Answer (score 3):

`const` fields are stored in assembly metatada. When you reference the assembly in some other assemblies, the `const` fields' VALUES are directly copied into the referencing assembly.

So if you ever decide to change a `const` field, you will have to recompile all assemblies that reference it to see the change.

For example, if in Assembly1 you have:

```
public class Class1
{
    public const string ConstString = "Const";
}
```

And reference it in Assembly2:

```
class Class2
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.ConstString);
    }
}
```

`Class1.ConstString` will be replaced at compile time with the value of the constant (`"Const"`).